# On the number of embeddings in algebraic closure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am having some trouble proving this statement:

For some field extension $L/M, (L \subset \overline{M})$ we denote by $\Delta_{L/M}$ the M-embeddings of $L$ into $\overline{M}.$

Consider the following extension tower $F \subset K \subset E$, where $K=F(\alpha)$ and $E=F(\alpha,\beta)$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in E$. Also consider $E \subset \overline{F}$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $F$. Then show that

$$
\left| \Delta_{E/F} \right| = \left| \Delta_{E/K} \right|\left| \Delta_{K/F} \right|.
$$

I know that $\left| \Delta_{K/F} \right|$ and $\left| \Delta_{E/K} \right|$ will be equal to the number of different roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ and the number of different roots of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$, respectively.
But I have some difficulties picturing what $\Delta_{E/F}$ looks like.

Any hints ? Thank you.

Comment: From $h \in K[y] \simeq F[x]/(g(x))[y]$ the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K\simeq F[x]/(g(x))$ you obtain $E \simeq F[x,y]/(g(x),h(x,y))$ having $\deg_{sep}(g)\deg_{sep}(h)$ $\ \ F$-embeddings into $\overline{F}$ (the separable degree is the number of distinct roots which stays the same under fields isomorphisms and embeddings)